# Second Queue does not print out the items from the first queue

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to simulate a can fruit factory. As the cans are sterilised 4 at a time, the filling takes place. Only the cans that are sterilised can be filled. How do I implement this? Because as for my output, it says that it sterilizes can 1,2,3,4, which means that the next stage, it it supposed to fill can 1, but instead, it fills can 5

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
ExecutionException {
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> belt = new 
LinkedBlockingQueue();
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> steril = new 
LinkedBlockingQueue(4);
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> fill = new 
LinkedBlockingQueue();
            ExecutorService factory = 
Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                can c = new can(i);
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Can" + c.canNo + " entered factory");
                //filling f = new filling(c, steril, fill);

                try {
                    Future<can> dentscan = factory.submit(new dentscanner(c, belt, steril, fill));
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    //factory.submit(f);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }
        }
    }



    class can {

        int canNo;
        boolean sterilized = false;

        public can(int canNo) {
            this.canNo = canNo;
        }
    }



        public dentscanner(can c, LinkedBlockingQueue<can> belt, LinkedBlockingQueue<can> steril, LinkedBlockingQueue fill) {
            this.c = c;
            this.belt = belt;
            this.steril = steril;
            this.fill = fill;
        }

        @Override
        public can call() throws Exception {
            ExecutorService factory = 
Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            sterilisation s = new sterilisation(c, belt, steril, fill);
            int dent = rand.nextInt(10);
            System.out.println("\tScanning for Can" + c.canNo 
+ " for Dents");
            if (dent == 3) {
                System.out.println("\t\tStatus: Dented");
                System.out.println("\t\t\tCan" + c.canNo + " 
Rejected");
                System.out.println("\t\t\tRemoved from belt");
                return null;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\t\tStatus:No Dents");
                System.out.println("\tPassing Can " + c.canNo + 
" for sterilisation");
                belt.put(c);
                factory.submit(s);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return c;
            }
        }

    }


    class sterilisation implements Runnable {

        can c;
        LinkedBlockingQueue<can> belt;
        LinkedBlockingQueue<can> steril;
        LinkedBlockingQueue<can> fill;
        int counter = 0;

        public sterilisation(can c, LinkedBlockingQueue<can> belt, LinkedBlockingQueue<can> steril, LinkedBlockingQueue fill) {
            this.c = c;
            this.belt = belt;
            this.steril = steril;
            this.fill = fill;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ExecutorService factory = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            filling f = new filling(c, steril, fill);
            try {
                can c = belt.take();
                steril.put(c);
                if (steril.size() == 4) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Can" + steril.take().canNo + " sterilised");
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                    c.sterilized = true;
                }
                if (c.sterilized) {
                    factory.submit(f);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    class filling implements Runnable {

        can c;
        LinkedBlockingQueue<can> steril;
        LinkedBlockingQueue<can> fill;

        public filling(can c, LinkedBlockingQueue<can> steril, LinkedBlockingQueue<can> fill) {
            this.c = c;
            this.steril = steril;
            this.fill = fill;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ExecutorService factory = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            try {
                fill.put(steril.take());
                System.out.println("Filling Can" + fill.take().canNo);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

        }

    }
```

Here is the output

```
Passing Can 4 for sterilisation
    Can1 sterilised
    Can2 sterilised
    Can3 sterilised
    Can4 sterilised
    ---------------------------------------
    Can5 entered factory
        Scanning for Can5 for Dents
            Status:No Dents
        Passing Can 5 for sterilisation
    Filling Can5
```

Comment: Can you also post how you are executing the code. i.e. the main method and any parameters that you are passing around

Comment: Edited is my main

Comment: The code still isn't complete. I dont know what dentscanner is. Post the classes with proper formatting and distinction.

Comment: Apologies, I have revised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but a few hints. Model the processes as threads. Sterilization is one thread, processing 4 cans at a time. Filling is another thread, processing one can at a time. Connect the processes (threads) with input and output queues (BlockingQueues):

```
---Q1--> Sterilization ---Q2--> Filling ---Q3-->  ?
```

After thinking and some experimentation you will find that every "process" has (at least) four properties in common. I'll give you the first two: Input queue and Output queue. The remaining two I leave as an exercise.